# Dimensionar console pra mais de 800x800 visual-c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Por que não consigo e como dimensionar a tela com `1400x900` "`width`x`height`"?
 Mais precisamente a largura pois vi que a altura consigo ampliar com mais de `800, 900` e com `1000` ela já ultrapassa a barra de ferramentas do windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

void resizeConsole(int, int);

int main()
{
    resizeConsole(1400, 900); //redimensionar a tela
    system("pause");
}
void resizeConsole(int width, int height)
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(console, &r);
    MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, width, height, TRUE);
}
```

Eu li quê, isso não funcionará porque a largura do console é limitada por padrão a 80 caracteres. E que preciso alterar o tamanho do buffer da tela para poder redimensionar a tela. Porém não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer isso!
 Alguém me entende?
 Redimensionar a largura com menos de 800 eu consigo, assim como na duvida desse entusiasta...
--> [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://daynhauhoc.com/t/hoi-cach-thay-doi-kich-thuoc-console-trong-c/34390) <--

Answer (score 0):

Não sei a q tipo de projetos se vai adequar este codigo mas deverias dar uma olhada nas GUI do c++ pois com elas será mais facil trabalhares a janela

Se quiseres tamanhos muito maiores do que o terminal permite podes dar duplo clicle na barra branca do terminal e ele vai expandir

mas se quiseres por codigo tlvs o codigo abaixo resolva senao e melhor mesmo trabalhares com uma GUI

mas para fazer o que precisas talvez seja melhor trabalhares com o SetConsoleWindowInfo e SetConsoleScreenBufferSize.

tens aqui um pequeno exemplo

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SMALL_RECT sr;
COORD consoleSize;
cout << "Tamanho original\nPressionar enter para continuar..." << endl;
cin.get();

consoleSize.X = 50; consoleSize.Y = 25;

sr.Top=sr.Left=0;
sr.Right=49; sr.Bottom=24;

SetConsoleWindowInfo(console, TRUE, &sr);
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(console, consoleSize);

cout << "50x25\nPressionar enter para continuar..." << endl;
cin.get();

consoleSize.X = 20; consoleSize.Y = 10;

sr.Right=19; sr.Bottom=9;

SetConsoleWindowInfo(console, TRUE, &sr);
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(console, consoleSize);

cout << "20x10\nPressionar enter para continuar..." << endl;
cin.get();

consoleSize.X = 80; consoleSize.Y = 25;

sr.Right=79; sr.Bottom=24;

SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(console, consoleSize);
SetConsoleWindowInfo(console, TRUE, &sr);
return 0;
}
```

edit:Tinha um pequeno erro no codigo mas ja funciona direito

Comment: Muito bom! Mas ele ainda não ampliar para além do tamanho original, apesar do duplo click  o console vai para o canto superior direto do monitor a altura pode até ampliar até o limite da Barra de ferramentas do windows porém a largura ainda não consegue ultrapassar do tamanho inicial.

Comment: melhor mesmo usar uma GUI voce com a GUI consegue expandir muito mesmo e vai resolver o seu problema
depois nao se esqueça de marcar a resposta para ajudar outras pessoas com o seu problema